# Why does a button not trigger my logout.php when a div does?

Tags: php, button, logout

I have a 'button', an 'a' inside with href="logout.php", it won't logout.

When I have the same code inside 'div' tags inside, it does.

Why is this? Feel free to quote URLs, I can find no instructive explanation!

Comment: sounds like bad markup. I don't think button tags have children.

Comment: post your complete source code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Button tags are expanded

```
<input type="button">
```

I don't recall any specification saying you can use links inside a button. Instead, link your Jquery or Javascript to the onclick of the button. Else it becomes completly useless to use a button tag cause what you want is to execute a href and not submit a form...

Answer (score 1):

You could create a button and place it in a form to submit a logout.

Like so:

```
<form action="logout.php">
    <input type="button" name="Logout">
</form>
```

Comment: The way you were doing it if its like this is bad markup.

    <button><a href="logout">logout</a></button>
or
    <input type="button"><a href="logout">logout</a></input>